# Google Drive API vs Dropbox API Android/Desktop

Tags: android, python, api, dropbox, google-drive-api

I got here a simple question for people that used to work with cloud storage API's.

I want to set up a client/server model where the client is Android and it uploads files periodically to the cloud. The server is a desktop application (using Python) that listen for changes on a folder and that downloads files to get data.

I read about Dropbox and GDrive and I was wondering which one is easier to handle for a beginner. I have those links for Android :

```
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/start/android
```

The Dropbox API seems to be much more simple on the surface !
Am I wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Loric, I work on the Dropbox API and we like to think the API is pretty simple. Definitely let us know if you have any specific questions!

Comment: Thanks for your support! And sure it is simple. You're doing a great job. Playing with the API by now, I would let you know if I have a problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has offered more services, and done more while costing the consumer less. Google is tough to beat, but Dropbox can match or beat Google in the storage wars. The real game changer is going to be Mailbox, and that is just coming on the market.

It appears as though the Google Docs document list APIs provide some level of programmatic access to Google Drive files. The documentation on the Google Drive developer site currently doesn't discuss that functionality at all, and says that apps "will not have any API access to files unless users have first installed the app in the Chrome Web Store." It's not clear yet if the Google Docs API is the path that Google is going to use for supporting arbitrary Google Drive access by desktop and mobile applications.

Hence I in my opinion for now use G drive. But who knows what new surprises are about to upraise. ;)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I will take a look on those solutions and try to explore the GDrive documentation. But from what I read in Dropbox doc, there was the examples one after another to read, write, check the changes on a file/folder. I hope there are examples too for Gdrive.

Comment: the examples are available GOOGLE it and the APIs are mostly self descriptive check GIThub if you are lucky you can get some demos from there. ;)
Have a nice codeful day :D

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has clear, public disclosed bandwidth limitations, while Google Drive does not. If you download a file many times on Google Drive, it could block it for 24 hours.

Dropbox has a clear limitation of 20GB or 200GB a day depending on your account, free or business. Google Drive, although free, does not clearly disclose its bandwidth limitations, so you are at risk of getting your downloads blocked.

Dropbox is very easy to use, and you can easily setup public shareable links, just like Google Drive. They both also have APIs.